# Problem converting pdf to jpg via ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have a problem converting pdf to jpg via ImageMagick.

The following command works successfully by producing a pdf file from a jpg file.

```
convert.exe -density 300 "C:\TEMP\testing.jpg" -depth 8 "C:\TEMP\testing.pdf"
```

However, reversing the process by converting the pdf file back to a jpg file does not seem to work.

Errors are not shown, but the output file is not produced.

```
convert.exe -density 300 "C:\TEMP\testing.pdf" -depth 8 "C:\TEMP\testing.jpg"
```

I have installed the latest imagemagick (ImageMagick-7.0.8-37-Q16-x64-dll.exe) from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php and ghostscript (9.27) from https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html both for Windows x64.

Your kind help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using v7 ImageMagick, you should use `magick <input> <operators> <output>` rather than `convert.exe` especially on Windows!

Comment: Yes I am using v7. I tried your suggention, but still not getting jpg file for output.

Comment: Try removing the `-density` and `-depth`, see if that makes a difference. Then try making a GIF or TGA as output and see if that works. Try `magick identify -list format` to see what formats your installation supports.

Comment: You can also use `magick -debug all ...`

Comment: Post your starting image so we can test. Also GS 9.27 must be very new. Perhaps downgrade to 9.25, 9.24 or 9.23. 9.26 was known to be buggy.

Comment: fmw42@You hit the nail on the head! GS9.27 is buggy. It works fine with GS9.25. Thank you very much!